# How to make an overlay on image when hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with img inside. Div is solidly bordered. I need the div to be backgrounded when hovered covering the image and the overlay should have a text at the center of it.

This is the code I have:

```
    <div class="picture">
<a href="product-link"><img src="product-img-link" /></a>
</div>
```

How can I do that? What is the easiest way for it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: People, I appreciate your help! Thank you a lot. May God grant you good health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

EDIT: Added vertically centered text too

HTML

```css
.picture {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.vertical-center {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.vertical-center span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.picture:hover > .overlay {
  display: block;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="vertical-center">
      <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="product-link">
    <img src="https://grd.me/m/img/logo.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
**html:**

```
<div class="picture">
    <a href="product-link"><img src="path" /></a>
    <div class="cover">
       cover
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
body{
  margin:0px;
}
.picture{
 position;relative;
 width:400px;
 height:250px;    
}
.picture img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
 .cover{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 background-color:green;
 height:250px;
 width:400px;
}
.picture:hover .cover{
  display:block;
}
```

**demo:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmfoh6jL/1/)

Comment: You did help me, but there are still some problems I get. Can we contact by email or Skype? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @ZafarGilfanov  Yes no problem. Can you tell me somewhere private your e-mail

Comment: Yes, contact me by Skype. My Skype ID is **zafar_12**

Comment: @ZafarGilfanov also choose an anwers as the best one. Than is the question closed

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
.flex-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background-image: url('http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/680934765/100-cotton-soft-outsole-baby-font-b-tiger-b-font-cartoon-skidproof-toddler-newborn-font-b.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
.flex-div a{
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
  background-color: rgba(40, 255, 40, 0.6);
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-div:hover a{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-div'><a href='#'>Click to get it!</a></div>
```

Comment: No, not something like yours. You did not use my example code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
    <div class="picture">
    <a href="#" class="product_slogan">
        Product Link Text
    </a>
    <img src="product-img-link" />
</div>

.picture{
    width:300px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

.product_slogan{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity:0;
    color:#fff;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

.picture:hover .product_slogan{
    opacity:1
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryc0x6ws/1/

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is really smth that I need. But on my site the background doesn't fit my image div. It appears at the top of the page.

Comment: Can you provide a link?.. You can make also something like this : .picture{ width:100%; background-image:url(url_to_your_image); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;} and then you can delete the img tag